# Swift Playground : How do I write a while function which doubles each day?

Tags: swift, while-loop, swift-playground

I need to create a loop which will show pennies each day and total for the months end. I couldn't create the loop as the playground keeps on multiplying infinitely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! There are definitely a lot of ways to solve this problem, but if I understand your question - this is how I would solve it.

#### Step 1 - Date Extension

First, I would start by making an extension to Date.

```swift
extension Date {
    
    /// The month component of the provided date.
    var month: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self)
    }
    
    /// Exactly one day before the provided date.
    var prevDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: self)!
    }
    
    /// Exactly one day after the provided date.
    var nextDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self)!
    }
    
}
```

These variables will make some of the later work, easier.

#### Step 2 - Variables

Then we can setup the variables.

- First, we get the start date - I am just instantiating a new Date object which defaults to *right now*.
- Along with that, we will define a variable where we can keep track of where we are in the iteration.
- Next, we need somewhere to keep track of the values over time.
- Lastly, a value to hold the starting value.

```swift
let startDate = Date() // Today, now.
var iterDate = startDate

var vals: [Date: Int] = [:]
let startingValue: Int = 1
```

#### Step 3 - The Loop

Now, the fun part - the loop.  This part will be documented in the code.

```swift
// Execute the loop until the end of the start date's month.
while iterDate.month == startDate.month {
    // First, check if this is the first iteration -
    if vals.count == 0 {
        // If so, there is nothing to double, so we just set the starting value.
        vals[iterDate] = startingValue
    } else {
        // If there are already values - get the previous days value, double it, and save.
        if let val = vals[iterDate.prevDay] {
            vals[iterDate] = val * 2
        }
    }
    
    // Lastly, move to the next day.
    iterDate = iterDate.nextDay
}
```

#### Step 4 - Final Value

Now that we have a dictionary of all of the values, as they grow, we can get the month-end value.  First, sort the dictionary - then get the value.  Getting the value this way means that you don't *need* to know the date.

```swift
let sortedVals = vals.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })

if let monthEnd = sortedVals.last {
    let monthEndVal = monthEnd.1
    // Use the value, here.
}
```

---

There it is - hope that solves the problem!

---

#### Full Code

```swift
import Foundation

extension Date {
    
    /// The month component of the provided date.
    var month: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self)
    }
    
    /// Exactly one day before the provided date.
    var prevDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: self)!
    }
    
    /// Exactly one day after the provided date.
    var nextDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self)!
    }
    
}

let startDate = Date() // Today, now.
var iterDate = startDate

var vals: [Date: Int] = [:]
let startingValue: Int = 1

// Execute the loop until the end of the start date's month.
while iterDate.month == startDate.month {
    // First, check if this is the first iteration -
    if vals.count == 0 {
        // If so, there is nothing to double, so we just set the starting value.
        vals[iterDate] = startingValue
    } else {
        // If there are already values - get the previous days value, double it, and save.
        if let val = vals[iterDate.prevDay] {
            vals[iterDate] = val * 2
        }
    }
    
    // Lastly, move to the next day.
    iterDate = iterDate.nextDay
}

let sortedVals = vals.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })

if let monthEnd = sortedVals.last {
    let monthEndVal = monthEnd.1
    // Use the value, here.
}
```